# "Flatten" a string of words in list

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

Given the following list (the actual list I have is longer than this, with at least 100 sublists in the list):

```
[[135, "Apple Banana"], [136, "Peach Watermelon"], [137, "Orange Steak"]]
```

What would be a "Pythonic way" to get the following list?

```
[[135, "Apple", "Banana"], [136, "Peach", "Watermelon"], [137, "Orange", "Steak"]]
```

I already have an implementation using for-loop.

```
myList = [[135, "Apple Banana"], [136, "Peach Watermelon"], [137, "Orange Steak"]]

temp_container = []

for subList in myList:
    temp_container = subList[1].split(" ")
    subList[1] = temp_container[0]
    subList.append(temp_container[1])
```

I am wondering if there is any better implementation? (Maybe using something like `[map(function, subList) for subList in myList]`? )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it with a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), unpacking the sublists and using [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) on the second item of each sublist:

```
In [1]: l = [[135, "Apple Banana"], [136, "Peach Watermelon"], [137, "Orange Steak"]]

In [2]: [[item0] + item1.split() for item0, item1 in l]
Out[2]: 
[[135, 'Apple', 'Banana'],
 [136, 'Peach', 'Watermelon'],
 [137, 'Orange', 'Steak']]
```

Or, without the unpacking:

```
In [3]: [[item[0]] + item[1].split() for item in l]
Out[3]: 
[[135, 'Apple', 'Banana'],
 [136, 'Peach', 'Watermelon'],
 [137, 'Orange', 'Steak']]
```

Comment: I'd say unpacking is the "most-Pythonic" though

Answer (score 1):

If

```
l = [[135, "Apple Banana"], [136, "Peach Watermelon"], [137, "Orange Steak"]]
```

then:

```
[[a, *b.split()] for [a, b] in l]
```

will give:

```
[[135, 'Apple', 'Banana'], [136, 'Peach', 'Watermelon'], [137, 'Orange', 'Steak']]
```

Edit: but not in Python 2.7, which this question is specifically tagged as.

Comment: Modify it to `[a] + b.split()` and it functions in Python 2.7 :)

Answer (score 1):

There are many solutions, this is the one that makes most sense to me:

```
>>> your_list = [[135, "Apple Banana"], [136, "Peach Watermelon"], [137, "Orange Steak"]]
>>> [[a] + b.split() for a, b in your_list]
[[135, 'Apple', 'Banana'], [136, 'Peach', 'Watermelon'], [137, 'Orange', 'Steak']]
```

It uses tuple unpacking to split between the `int` and the `str` and simply creates a new list which gets the split of the `str` added to it.